# JComboBox remains open when windows lose focus

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am given a task to port a java application with a JComboBox from OS2 to Windows.

The JComboBox in OS2(JRE1.4) has a behavoir that when the popup is open, user click on other windows, the popup remains open. But when that run in Windows (JRE1.6), user clicked on other windows, JComboBox will close automatically.

How can i achieve the same behavior in Windows? I want it remain opened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. not possible, `JComboBoxe`s popup always to hide on `focusLost`, these [changes were fixed in Java 1.4](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/combo-box-no-action/)
2. have to create own `Component` that simulating funcionalities from `JComboBox`, `popup window` should be based on `JDialog / JWindow` (strongly don't suggest that...)

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it will work if use JComboBox source code from old java version? Where can that be found? I can only find latest one...

Comment: @Johnny there are two prerequisities, compile Java code in JDK1.4 and running on PC where is top JVM Java1.4, It's not worth the effort, an great alternative could be use Java Calendars, popup window is based (most o them) on JDialog/JWindow

Comment: Finally, i made a custom component inheriting JComboBox, replacing all its mouse/key handlers, showPopup/hidePopup with my own to show/hide a custom JList. Not a elegant solution, but works with minimal coding.